# how to install joomla 1.7.3

Tags: joomla, installation

I don't know how to install Joomla 1.7.3 and it's hard to know from joomla web page. Can anybody tell me how to install joomla 1.7.3 step-by-step.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

There's an old guide here, although it still mostly applies:

http://help.joomla.org/content/category/15/99/132/

In short: Create a database, Upload the Joomla files, follow the installer. In more detail:

- Make sure you meet the system requirements:
  http://www.joomla.org/technical-requirements.html
- Create a MySQL database (note down the name, username, and password to access it)
- Get the Joomla files from here:
  http://www.joomla.org/download.html
- Upload all the files from that package to your hosting
- Browse to your site - the Joomla installer will automatically run. There's a guide for the steps here:
  http://docs.joomla.org/Installer
- Follow the instructions and fill in the boxes in the Joomla installer.
- Once the installation is complete, delete the 'installation' folder (the installer will tell you to do this).
- You now have Joomla :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked this page? http://docs.joomla.org/Installation
It provides a step by step installation guide, I think it's quite easy to install Joomla. Generally talking, all you have to do is:

1. Download the latest Joomla version ( I guess you already did this )
2. Unzip the downloaded file, then copy it into your webroot ( if you have multiple sites, you should create a folder within your webroot dir and copy the files there )
3. Access via your browser your web dir, and installation process will start.

It's important that you check that your Apache user is able to read and write your Joomla files. If you're using virtual hosts, you should also create and configure the new virtual host.